# Why does searching for larger strings in a `reversed` string take more time than slice reversing?

Tags: python, performance, reverse

As I read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-reversed-vs-1-which-one-is-faster/), reversing a string using the `reversed` function is more efficient than slice notation,`string[::-1]`. But when I tried it myself, I observed different results.

First, I tried to make a very big string. And then I tried to check how much time it takes to check whether a string exists in the large one or not. This is what I did:

```py
In [1]: large = "abcdefgijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_=+0}{QWERT"                                                                           

In [2]: large = 1000*large                                                                                                                           

In [3]: large = 1000*large  

In [5]: len(large)                                                                                                                                   
Out[5]: 56000000

In [6]: %time "a" in large[::-1]                                                                                                                     
CPU times: user 63 ms, sys: 43.4 ms, total: 106 ms
Wall time: 106 ms
Out[6]: True

In [7]: %time "a" in reversed(large)                                                                                                                 
CPU times: user 11 µs, sys: 1 µs, total: 12 µs
Wall time: 17.6 µs
Out[7]: True
```

If I check the existence of only 1 char in `large`, `reversed` is much faster, but when I attempt it for bigger strings, the result changes:

```py
In [8]: %time "ab" in large[::-1]                                                                                                                    
CPU times: user 99.2 ms, sys: 44.1 ms, total: 143 ms
Wall time: 143 ms
Out[8]: False

In [9]: %time "ab" in reversed(large)                                                                                                                
CPU times: user 1.73 s, sys: 4.48 ms, total: 1.73 s
Wall time: 1.74 s
Out[9]: False
In [10]: %time "abc" in large[::-1]                                                                                                                  
CPU times: user 125 ms, sys: 20 ms, total: 145 ms
Wall time: 145 ms
Out[10]: False

In [11]: %time "abc" in reversed(large)                                                                                                              
CPU times: user 1.72 s, sys: 6.52 ms, total: 1.73 s
Wall time: 1.74 s
Out[11]: False
```

What's happening under the hood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two are not the same, and may produce different boolean outcomes. For instance:

```
s = "ab"
print("ba" in s[::-1])  # True
print("ba" in reversed(s))  # False
```

The `in` operator on a *string* has different behaviour: it looks for a substring match. The `in` operator on a iterator will try to find a match on individually iterated values, i.e. single characters in this case.

So you cannot really compare these like that.

As to why it is slower to get a `False` outcome: the iterator will create separate strings for each iterated character to which then the needle string ("ba") is compared from scratch.

In the string version, there is an optimised search algorithm to find a substring in a larger string, which is *one* operation for Python. The efficient string search algorithm is implemented in lower level code, like C.